# Propose to the user to rewrite functions with lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I'm doing tests to understand lambdas. I am trying to offer to the users the ability to rewrite a function directly in the main function. Let me explain:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual bool execute() {};
};

class B : public A {
public:
    bool execute() { cout << "Execute in B" << endl; }
};

int main() {

    B newB;
    newB.execute();
    newB.execute() { cout << "Execute in New B" << endl; } ;
    newB.execute();

    return 0;
}
```

This source code doesn't work because it's illegal to rewrite a function like that. What would be for you, the best way to rewrite a function like that in C ++ 14? With lambda? Without lambda?

I want do like in Javascript, overloading a function like that: newB.somefunction = function(...) { ... };. I want the function to be written in source code by a user of my Library. In a way a callback function.

my question is the following: How to write a callback function or Lambda expressions to rewrite a method outside a class/object?

Solution proposed by Exagon with variable :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
class B {

public:
    int global=0;
    std::function<void()> execute{
        [](){
            std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
        }
    };
};

int main() {

    B newB;
    newB.execute();
    newB.execute();

    newB.execute = [newB](){std::cout << newB.global << "  = FOOBAR\n";};

    newB.execute();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the function to be written in source code by a user of your Library? or do you want the function to be written at run-time by the user of the application? ...For the latter, check [ChaiScript](http://chaiscript.com/)

Comment: Hello ChaiScript, I want do like in Javascript, overloading a function like that: newB.somefunction = function(...) { ... };. I want the function to be written in source code by a user of my Library, exactly.

Comment: Sounds like you want some form of callback. Change your class to accept a `std::function<>` int he constructor and just call that when you would have called execute.

Comment: I could not remember the term "callback". thank you

Comment: Who are your users and why are you offering them to write code? Is your product a library or a compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `std::function` from the `functional` header.
Then make a `std::function` member and create a setter for this member.
the `execute` member function need to call this `std::function` member.
you can pass a lambda into the setter method.
here is my approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class B {
public:
    void execute() {_f();}
    void setFunction(std::function<void()> f){ _f = f;}
private:
    std::function<void()> _f{[](){std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;}};
};

int main() {

    B newB;
    newB.execute();
    newB.execute();

    newB.setFunction([](){std::cout << "FOOBAR\n";});

    newB.execute();
    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
Hello World
Hello World
FOOBAR
```

Since you are after something "JavaScript-like" you could do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
class B {
public:
    std::function<void()> execute{
        [](){
            std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
        }
    };
};

int main() {

    B newB;
    newB.execute();
    newB.execute();

    newB.execute = [](){std::cout << "FOOBAR\n";};

    newB.execute();
    return 0;
}
```

Which has the same output.

[here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OhFeEallB9awdtMx) is a live demo